# How to search for text with non-ascii letters

Tags: postgresql

I have `locations` table with `city` attribute. These are polish city names so it can be Łódź, Gdańsk etc. (names with non-ascii characters).

How can I do search for these fields that will give me results like this:

```
search_term => city

'Lodz' => 'Łódź'
'gdansk' => 'Gdańsk'
'Łodz' => 'Łódź'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`translate()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html), e.g.:

```
create or replace function lower_pl(text)
returns text language sql immutable as $$
    select translate(lower($1), 'ąćęłńóśźż', 'acelnoszz')
$$;
```

Test:

```
create table cities (name text);
insert into cities values
('Łódź'), ('Gdańsk');

select *
from cities
where lower_pl(name) = lower_pl('Łodz');

 name 
------
 Łódź
(1 row)
```

Comment: I would normally advise against using `translate`, and instead recommend converting to NFD and stripping modifiers (as this would provide universal support, not just for Polish, and you would be sure not to forget any exotic combinations), but `Ł` is an exception (like `Ø`), as it can't be decomposed, so you do indeed need to use `translate` :-( You might want to make the function `IMMUTABLE`, though, so you can add an index using the function.

Comment: @jcaron - right, the function should be declared as immutable. Updated.

Comment: Another option is the `unaccent()` function: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/unaccent.html